# Python Error xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 10 1

Tags: python

I use python to extract Sprite from a Plist file. But i getting this error  " xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 101" and don't known how to resolve it.
Anyone can help me. Thank you so much.
This is python code :

```
import os
import plistlib
from PIL import Image


class Matrix(object):
    def __init__(self, src_box, clip_box, offset):
        self.src_box = src_box
        self.clip_box = clip_box
        self.offset = offset
        self.src_size = [self.src_box[2] - self.src_box[0], self.src_box[3] - self.src_box[1]]
        self.clip_size = [self.clip_box[2] - self.clip_box[0], self.clip_box[3] - self.clip_box[1]]


class TextureUnpacker(object):
    @classmethod
    def split_with_plist(cls, plist, save=None):
        plist = os.path.abspath(plist)
        if save is None:
            save = plist + '_split'
        else:
            save = os.path.abspath(save)

        dt = plistlib.readPlist(plist)
        metadata, frames = dt['metadata'], dt['frames']
        format_version = metadata['format']
        big_img = Image.open(metadata['realTextureFileName'])
        for frame, info in frames.iteritems():
            if format_version == 2:
                info = cls.parse_as_plist_v2(info)
            elif format_version == 3:
                info = cls.parse_as_plist_v3(info)
            else:
                raise Exception('not support version' + str(format_version))
            cls.generate_little_image(big_img, info, os.path.join(save, frame))

    @classmethod
    def generate_little_image(cls, big_img, info, path):
        little_img = Image.new('RGBA', info['sz'])
        region = big_img.crop(info['box'])
        if info['rotated']:
            # region = region.rotate(90, expand=1)
            region = region.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
        little_img.paste(region, info['xy'])
        dir_ = os.path.dirname(path)
        if not os.path.exists(dir_):
            os.makedirs(dir_)
        little_img.save(path)

    @classmethod
    def parse_as_plist_v2(cls, info):
        """
        {
            'frame': '{{1,1},{430,635}}',
            'offset': '{2,-2}',
            'rotated': False,
            'sourceSize': '{639,639}'
        }
        """
        info['frame'] = cls.__convert_rect(info['frame'])
        info['offset'] = cls.__convert_point(info['offset'])
        info['sourceSize'] = cls.__convert_point(info['sourceSize'])

        rotated = info['rotated']
        if rotated:
            box = (info['frame'][0], info['frame'][1],
                   info['frame'][0] + info['frame'][3],
                   info['frame'][1] + info['frame'][2])
        else:
            box = (info['frame'][0], info['frame'][1],
                   info['frame'][0] + info['frame'][2],
                   info['frame'][1] + info['frame'][3])

        x = info['offset'][0] + (info['sourceSize'][0] - info['frame'][2]) / 2
        y = (info['sourceSize'][1] - info['frame'][3]) / 2 - info['offset'][1]

        return {
            'box': box,
            'rotated': rotated,
            'xy': (x, y),
            'sz': info['sourceSize']
        }

    @classmethod
    def parse_as_plist_v3(cls, info):
        """
        {
            'aliases': [],
            'spriteOffset': '{1,-1}',
            'spriteSize': '{433,637}',
            'spriteSourceSize': '{639,639}',
            'textureRect': '{{1,1},{433,637}}',
            'textureRotated': False
        }
        """
        info['spriteSize'] = cls.__convert_point(info['spriteSize'])
        info['spriteOffset'] = cls.__convert_point(info['spriteOffset'])
        info['textureRect'] = cls.__convert_rect(info['textureRect'])
        info['spriteSourceSize'] = cls.__convert_point(info['spriteSourceSize'])

        rotated = info['textureRotated']
        if rotated:
            box = (info['textureRect'][0], info['textureRect'][1],
                   info['textureRect'][0] + info['textureRect'][3],
                   info['textureRect'][1] + info['textureRect'][2])
        else:
            box = (info['textureRect'][0], info['textureRect'][1],
                   info['textureRect'][0] + info['textureRect'][2],
                   info['textureRect'][1] + info['textureRect'][3])

        x = info['spriteOffset'][0] + (info['spriteSourceSize'][0] - info['spriteSize'][0]) / 2
        y = (info['spriteSourceSize'][1] - info['spriteSize'][1]) / 2 - info['spriteOffset'][1]

        return {
            'box': box,
            'rotated': rotated,
            'xy': (x, y),
            'sz': info['spriteSourceSize']
        }

    @classmethod
    def __convert_rect(cls, rect):
        s = rect.replace('{', '')
        s = s.replace('}', '')
        x, y, w, h = s.split(',')
        return [int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)]

    @classmethod
    def __convert_point(cls, pt):
        s = pt.replace('{', '')
        s = s.replace('}', '')
        x, y = s.split(',')
        return [int(x), int(y)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    TextureUnpacker.split_with_plist(sys.argv[1])
```

And this is plist file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>frames</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Sprite_ID1212</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{0, 0}, {640, 1156}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0, -0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <string>false</string>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0, 0}, {640, 1156}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{640, 1156}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>Sprite_ID160</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{644, 0}, {640, 1156}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0, -0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <string>false</string>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0, 0}, {640, 1156}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{640, 1156}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>Sprite_ID1113</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{1288, 0}, {640, 1156}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0, -0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <string>false</string>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0, 0}, {640, 1156}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{640, 1156}</string>
            </dict>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>format</key>
            <string>2</string>
            <key>realTextureFileName</key>
            <string>atlas_ID101.png</string>
            <key>size</key>
            <string>{2048, 2048}</string>
            <key>smartupdate</key>
            <string>$Potion:Smartupdate:$</string>
            <key>textureFileName</key>
            <string>atlas_ID101.png</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Your document seems to be missing a closing </dict> tag near the end. Might not be the only issue, though.

Comment: Oh, Because plist file is too long, so i write a part of it.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate a problem in the file, so you should try to find where it is. You can start with a minimal plist file and add more and more of the content, or start with the full file and delete parts of it until it parses. The general tips about minimal, working examples also apply: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I see, but i only know a little about Python. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your file through `xmllint` and it would not parse it.  The `<dict>` tag on line 4 has no corresponding `</dict>` tag.  Either remove the tag or find an appropriate place to close it.  I suspect that nested `<dict>` structures are confusing the matter.